What is interactive review stage in a journal's review process useful for?
I am in the process of revision of my manuscript that I have received feedback from reviewers. In the journal the paper is in the "interactive review" stage. I want to know what are the benefits of this stage? If I want to communicate with referees, for which purposes and matters can I send them my comments? Can I ask them whether the revision I have done is enough before submitting the the revised version to the editor?  (Frontiers journals)

Perhaps name the publisher? I'm unfamiliar with what this is.

A reviewer has a larger task than a reasoned yes/no answer for acceptance. One of the most important task is contributing to the comprehensibility of the final version (if accepted). This task becomes easier if there is some feed-back. Another reason is that reviewers are fallible and can misunderstand. For example, a reviewer might deem a result to be an application of a known result or method, when in reality it is not. The author can point this out and improve the paper by explaining better why the paper is novel.
There seems to me (from my limited perspective) a push towards extending these interactions between reviewers and authors, while maintaining anonymity.

Since the question is not specifying a journal, this response will reflect the open review process of Copernicus journals. The point is to allow anyone to comment on a manuscript rather than the traditional way of having a editor appointed set of, typically, anonymous reviewers, review a manuscript. Obviously review procedures vary between fields and also between journals so I am only able to provide a partial answer reflecting the publishing environment, with which I am familiar.
When a manuscript is submitted to a Copernicus journal it will be posted as a 'Discussion'. This means the submitted manuscript will be posted openly for anyone to read and comment on. At the same time journal editors will source reviewers to perform a traditional review of the paper. These reviews, along with any comments provided by the reading public of the manuscript will be posted with the manuscript for public viewing. The combined invited reviews and public opinions need to be responded to by the authors which leads to a decision by the editors on the continued faith of the manuscript.
As far as I know, no fixed open review process has been established as a norm. Hence, details in any open review process will be specific to the journal or publisher of the journal. I am convinced efforts on open review will converge, but now they will be journal specific.

It is a journal from Frontiers
